# Why is this markdown for a link not showing properly?

Tags: support, markdown, tag-wiki-excerpt

The Stack Exchange (Personal Productivity) markdown [right here](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/tags/srs/info) is showing literally rather than as a named link. Don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag wiki excerpts do not support Markdown formatting, by design.

Comment: Is there a way to put a "clickable link" in a "Tag wiki excerpt"? And why is it designed that way?

Comment: No, it can only be plain text. Since the excerpt in places like the [tags list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags), the feeling was that allowing formatting could create excerpts that would be distracting or confusing for users.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation, but at least I know I can't do it. Thanks for the answer. @Tim